# What does this error mean that I'm getting whilst trying to install Oracle SQL onto a Linux server?

Tags: sql-server, linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to install `Oracle SQL Developer` onto a Linux server via the `Windows 8.1` operating system. I am downloading the packages from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

I am then installing the `Linux RPM` package from that site.

I am then moving it from the Windows 8.1 operating system (that it was downloaded onto) onto the Linux server (via WinSCP).

I am then opening up the Linux server on Putty and attempting to install the SQL Developer by using the following command:

```
rpm -Uvh sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

I am then recieving this error:

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this issue, I have searched Google and no useful results have popped up.

Comment: Why don't you just install it from the repos? What is your linux flavor, version?

Comment: @Core What do you mean by "repos"? I do apologise, I am not familar with Linux at all, this is the first time I've ever used it.

Comment: I see, so basically each flavor of Linux comes with predefined repositories that host files for each version and will download and install them much easier than finding the RPM's yourself. If you tell me what Linux flavor you run (Ex. Ubuntu, CentOS, RedHat) I can tell you the easiest way to install the SQL server.

Comment: It seems I may have misread your question, you have an SQL server already and are looking for a graphical interface?

Comment: Okay, so you have an SQL Server already? And what server is that, (Ex. MySQL, pgSQL)

Comment: @Core Of wait wait wait, No the server I'm using isn't an SQL server, it was previously used to host a website, do I need to buy a special server for this or can I adapt my current server?

Comment: No no, I'm asking if you have something like MySQL installed on your server already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68100/discussion-between-james-and-core).

Comment: @Core can we continue in chat please?

Answer (score 2):

On Debian do ( as the message says ) not install the rpm. Last time I did it like this (on Ubuntu though):

```
# Download "for other platforms" 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

# install packages to transform
sudo apt-get install debhelper sqldeveloper-package
sudo apt-get install tofrodos

# create links
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/todos /usr/bin/unix2dos

# transform noarch package to deb package 
# (-b workdir)
make-sqldeveloper-package -b /tmp/ORA sqldeveloper-3.0.04.34-no-jre.zip

# install deb package
sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb 

# after installation  maybe you'll have to set jdk path
touch ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk #i.e. /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

Found it here: http://timony.com/mickzblog/2010/01/09/install-oracle-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-karmic/

Comment: Don't know your configuration/your users permissions. `sudo` is just used to execute commands as superuser.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb `
Where exactly did this come from? I am getting this error:
`dpkg -i sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb
dpkg: error processing sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb`

Comment: I'm not sure, if you're not missing some real basics...you _had_ the deb-File in the directory where you called the command?

Comment: @evilive - minor note that the version 4 sqldeveloper now requires java version 7.  On my Fedora system I have both the openjdk and oracle's jdk in their own directories. When sqldeveloper first starts, it will ask for the location of the jdk to be used, which I pointed to the oracle jdk. Other than the resource hit that the installed programs demands on my small system, I am able to run simultaneously sqldeveloper (that uses oracle jdk) and other java programs (that uses openjdk).

Comment: @evilive Which command is that? I've run all of the commands upto `dpkg -i sqldeveloper_3.0.04.34+0.2.3-1_all.deb` which is when I get that error, I don't know whether I could be in the wrong directory?

Comment: @James - I think the version you're using is incorrect. For example, the line that starts with 'make-' would be:  make-sqldeveloper-package -b /tmp/ORA sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: @maurice Yes, I've changed that, however, am still encountering the following error:

`dpkg -i sqldevelopedpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb
dpkg: error processing sqldevelopedpkg (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing -i (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldevelopedpkg
 -i
 sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb
`

Comment: @James - Does the file exist? Do ls -l *.deb

Comment: @maurice upon running that command it returns 

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 234451232 Jan  3 17:01 sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1_all.deb`

And yes, that is the exact file name I am using to attempt to run the `dpkg` command.

Comment: @James - actually, the error you showed did not have the same exact name: sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb (from your previous message) versus sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1_all.deb (from the ls -l command).

Comment: @maurice Yes, I am aware of that, but when I am still getting the error after changing it.

`dpkg -i sqldevelopedpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb
dpkg: error processing sqldevelopedpkg (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing -i (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldevelopedpkg
 -i
 sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1.deb
`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so from what I can understand so far, you have an SQL server (MySQL) installed already. If you have an Apache installation (web server) you should be able to have a web interface for this, which will make it much easier on your part.

Otherwise, if you do not have Apache, you can install it by using

`apt-get install apache2`

and then you'll need PHP

`apt-get install php5 php-pear php5-mysql`

You'll have to restart apache

`service apache2 restart`

or

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

and then install phpmyadmin

`apt-get install phpmyadmin`

use `su -` for superuser access.

and then (at least with my experience) you should be able to go to `yoururl.com/phpmyadmin` and you should be able to login there.

I hope this helps.

Edit: For some reason Debian (at least his version) lacks sudo. I feel that phpmyadmin will be the easiest way to manage the database.